# C# get name of the JSON object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I´ve got a JSON stored in a string named `resultString` it looks like this:

```
{"BRC1": {"image": "9b.jpg", "query": "led", "status": "ok", "data": {"value": {"LED_1": "OFF", "LED_2": "OFF", "LED_3": "OFF", "LED_4": "RED", "LED_5": "RED", "SILA": "ON", "ASLED": "ORANGE"}}}}
```

Now I want to get the value `"BRC1"` as string.

Comment: `data["BRC1"]` will return the *value* of the `BRC1` property - which is an object. It's not a single string. If you want the JSON representation of the whole object, you could just use `data["BRC1"].ToString()`

Comment: This gives me the the whole content of the JSON but I just want the "BRC1" as string....

Comment: It's really unclear why you'd expect `data["BRC1"]` to return "BRC1" - if you know the key you're using for the indexer, and that's all you want, you don't need to use the indexer. I've answered assuming you *actually* just want the name of the first property in the object...

Comment: As an aside, `JObject data = JObject.Parse(resultString)` is a simpler way of doing the parsing.

Comment: Sorry when I Was unclear in my question. The value BRC1 is in my code not always the same. I just simplified it.
But as you assumed I am searching for the name of the  first property

Comment: I would strongly advise you to edit your question - it's pretty unclear at the moment, and it was pretty much a lucky guess...

Comment: @Exix You are very confusing. You should already have learned that there is a name of a property, and there is a value of the same property. What is changing? the name or probably value? or maybe both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need just BRC1 value as  a json string and you don't know a root  property name try this

```
string rootName = JObject.Parse(json).Properties().First().Name; // "BRC1"
    
string  rootJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(rootJson));
```

result

```
{"image":"9b.jpg","query":"led","status":"ok","data":{"value":{"LED_1":"OFF","LED_2":"OFF","LED_3":"OFF","LED_4":"RED","LED_5":"RED","SILA":"ON","ASLED":"ORANGE"}}}
```

or if you want it as escaped string

```
var rootJsonEscaped = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootJson)
```

result

```
"{\"image\":\"9b.jpg\",\"query\":\"led\",\"status\":\"ok\",\"data\":{\"value\":{\"LED_1\":\"OFF\",\"LED_2\":\"OFF\",\"LED_3\":\"OFF\",\"LED_4\":\"RED\",\"LED_5\":\"RED\",\"SILA\":\"ON\",\"ASLED\":\"ORANGE\"}}}"
```

or if you want it formatted

```
string rootJson = JObject.Parse(json).Properties().First().Value.ToString();
```

result

```
{
  "image": "9b.jpg",
  "query": "led",
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "value": {
      "LED_1": "OFF",
      "LED_2": "OFF",
      "LED_3": "OFF",
      "LED_4": "RED",
      "LED_5": "RED",
      "SILA": "ON",
      "ASLED": "ORANGE"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: JObject.Parse(json).Properties().First().Name; was I was searching for, thank you!
I was also missing using System.Linq;. Now it works

Answer (score 1):

If you just want "the name of the first property in the object" then you can use:

```cs
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultString);
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>> pairs = data;
string firstName = pairs.FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

`firstName` will be null if the object is actually empty.

Comment: It doesn't find the IEnumerable do I have to add a reference?

Comment: @Exix: You may need to add a `using` directive for the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, but VS should offer to do that for you...